# Force.com URL redirects for detail page?

Tags: force.com, url, redirect

I have a requirement where I should not let customer community users see pages like ***communitydomain/s/recordlist/Contact/Recent*** and ***/s/detail/{recordid}***.
Is there any way I can achieve this? I tried using URL redirects in site.com studio but no luck yet.

Comment: Can you check if [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/245058/lightning-community-how-to-hide-disable-remove-generic-record-pages) helps you achieve this.

Comment: Thanks @ShivankurNaikwade ! The link was helpful as I was able to remove components on generic pages like Record details and record list.

Comment: Thanks for acknowledging, glad it worked for you..!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to create an empty community template and override the page with it - so now if someone opens the page he sees a blank page.

OR

The other trick is to edit that profile and remove the read access to that object at profile level. Once the read access is invoked, the User even if they have access to record they wont be able to access the content via URL hacking or directly hitting the Salesforce Rest Endpoint(Community user is API enabled, so it can hit the SF rest endpoint and access data of records which you haven't' provided access via UI)